# Dynamically create DLL export functions without having the preprocessor involved in MSVC 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, dllexport, visual-c++-2015

Is it possible to dynamically create `__declspec(dllexport)`'ed functions without having the preprocessor involved in MSVC 2015?

I'm creating a DLL *plugin-creation* toolkit for some kind of measurement software and want to make the later *client-programmer* being able to add some kind of "extra-features" to the plugin in the `DllMain`, e.g.:

```
// Create a new instance of the custom driver
MyPluginDriver *myPluginDriver = new MyPluginDriver();

// Assign it to the core DLL
pluginCore.addDriver(myPluginDriver);
```

For each of this `addDriver`calls, the DLL later has to provide a callback function, whose name can be freely chosen. The main app expects the names of those functions getting passed by request in another callback.

So, what would be the 'best practice' for generating those `extern "C"` functions dynamically whithout `#define`'s and stuff?

Maybe some kind of *Lambda* way?

EDIT:
I think I've forgot to mention that it's a commercially available measurement software for which I'm writing that PDK. It's a **fixed interface** (and a fairly complex one, too) of hard-coded and expected function names by the app for the general callbacks. There's only that particular callback expecting some function names to call for measurement cycles which is relevant here.

Comment: A client programmer just needs to implement the interface. I'd provide a PluginDriver.h with an interface (class of just virtual functions) they can inherit from in there application.

After that they can do whatever they want in the DLL as long as it works with the provided interface, so as long as you make the DLL functions get enough info from events it should be pretty robust.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've to make something more clear. Please see my edit.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the following MSDN article may be quite helpful: [Exporting from a DLL Using DEF Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx)

Comment: You cannot manufacture exported functions at run time, if that's what you are asking. They have to be set up at link time. It's kind of a weird interface you have, where the main app expects function names to be passed to it, only to turn around and use `GetProcAddress` to convert them into function pointers (or so I presume). Why not just take function pointers to begin with?

Comment: It's because a plugin DLL can itself contain a custom amount of _variables_, _commands_ and _drivers_. Each of them gets it's own callback. The software is _DIAdem_ by _National Instruments_.